# Jenkinsfile Unterminated quoted string

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

My Jenkinsfile build fails with `Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string`

This stage which fails:

```
stage('Clean Volume') {
    steps {
        sh '''
            docker images --format="{{.Repository}} {{.Tag}} {{.ID}}" |
                grep -v "latest" |
                cut -d ' ' -f3 |
                xargs docker rmi -f"
            '''         
     }
}
```

What is the problem with syntax here?

Comment: cut -d ' ' -f3  could you use double quotes here?

Comment: @Armando Ballaci no parser doesn't work with double quotes in cases like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With all the upsides of the triple single-quote string, there is a natural consequence of needing to escape single quotes and backslashes that are part of our string.

```
def specialCharacters = '''hello \'John\'. This is backslash - \\ \nSecond line starts here'''
```

Comment: I add to cut : `cut -d \' \' -f3` but same error. I think the problem  is `{{`

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
xargs docker rmi -f"
```

ends with a starting `"` symbol that is never closed.